# Programmatically created a folder with very bad name: unable to move, delete or rename; also interferes with GitHub publishing

Tags: python-2.7, windows-8, github-for-windows, shutil

I programmatically created a folder with a bad name using `os.makedir`:

`A:\cncell\core\`A:\cncell\notes\2015_SEP_5\run_0_NC=1_TT=10000_NT=5000_coa=0_coa_degr=1_NN=16_(75x75)`

I have tried to differentiate between the directory the folder is in (in code format), and the name of the directory itself (in normal text). Just to reiterate and clarify, the directory the bad folder is in:
`A:\cncell\core`

While the name of the bad folder itself is:

`A:\cncell\notes\2015_SEP_5\run_0_NC=1_TT=10000_NT=5000_coa=0_coa_degr=1_NN=16_(75x75)`

I am unable to rename it, since I get the following error:

`The file name, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.`

I tried to delete it using the following methods (apart from the obvious Windows GUI methods), but I get the same `file name, directory name, ...volume label syntax...incorrect` error:

- 7zip's file manager: https://superuser.com/questions/78434/how-to-delete-directories-with-path-names-too-long-for-normal-delete
- Python's `os.rmdir` (it is an empty directory): `os.rmdir("A:\\cncell\\core\\'A:\\cncell\\notes\\2015_SEP_5\\run_0_NC=1_TT=10000_NT=5000_coa=0_coa_degr=1_NN=16_(75x75)'")`
- Python's `shutil.rmtree`:
  `shutil.rmtree("A:\\cncell\\core\\'A:\\cncell\\notes\\2015_SEP_5\\run_0_NC=1_TT=10000_NT=5000_coa=0_coa_degr=1_NN=16_(75x75)'")`
- Windows `cmd`'s `rmdir`:

`rmdir /S "A:\\cncell\\core\\'A:\\cncell\\notes\\2015_SEP_5\\run_0_NC=1_TT=10000_NT=5000_coa=0_coa_degr=1_NN=16_(75x75)'"`

I get the same error with all of them.

This is particularly bad because it also interfere's with publishing the parent directory on GitHub.

What can I try next?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I switched onto Ubuntu, accessed the directory there, and deleted it.

Comment: For future reference, in Windows you could do probably do this using the long path format, i.e., `rd \\?\a:\cncell\core\A:\cnell...`